# When (or what is the meaning of) $I \propto E^2$?

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, energy, poynting-vector

For a monochromatic plane wave: $$\mathbf E = \mathbf E _0e^{i(\mathbf k \cdot \mathbf r -\omega t)},\qquad \mathbf H = \dfrac{\mathbf B}{\mu _0}= \mathbf H_0e^{i(\mathbf k \cdot \mathbf r-\omega t)},$$
it's straightforward to show, using Maxwell's equations, that the Poynting vector $\mathbf S = \mathbf E \times \mathbf H$ is given (in MKS units) by$$\mathbf S = \varepsilon _0cE_0^2 \cos ^2 (\mathbf k \cdot \mathbf r - \omega t)\mathbf n,$$
where $\mathbf n = \mathbf k /k$ is the direction of propagation of the wave, so that the average energy flux in that direction is $$I= \overline {\mathbf S \cdot \mathbf n}=\lim _{T\to \infty} \intop ^T \mathbf S \cdot \mathbf n \text dt\propto E_0^2.$$

This relation is usually (compare, for example [1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486659577)) assumed as valid. That is, the irradiance is defined (or assumed to be) proportional to the average of the square of the electric field ([1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486659577) puts directly $I =  \overline {\mathbf E \cdot \mathbf E ^*}$) *even when the field is the superposition* of two plane harmonic waves.

Now, if the two waves (say $\mathbf E _0i, \mathbf k _i$ for $i=1,2$) share the same direction of propagation, I see no problem in the definition. But when the two directions are different, it's easy to see that the magnitude of the Poynting vector isn't strictly proportional to $(\mathbf E_1+\mathbf E_2)^2$. Moreover the direction of $\mathbf S$ is a quite complicated function of $\mathbf n _1 ,\mathbf n _2, \mathbf E _1, \mathbf E _2$ (in the case of two linearly polarized waves one has: $$\frac{1}{\varepsilon _0 c}\mathbf S = E_1 ^2 \mathbf n _1 + E_2 ^2 \mathbf n _2 + (\mathbf n _1 +\mathbf n _2)\mathbf E _1 \cdot \mathbf E _2 - (\mathbf n _1 \cdot \mathbf E _2 ) \mathbf E _1 - (\mathbf n _2 \cdot \mathbf E _1) \mathbf E _2.$$
As an extreme example, if one has two waves travelling in opposite direction, with $\mathbf k _2 = -\mathbf k _1$ and $\mathbf E _1 = \mathbf E _2,$ the flux of energy is clearly zero, while $I=4E^2$ according to the above definitions.

On the other hand, from the above expression, it is seen that if $\mathbf n _2 = \mathbf n _1 +\delta \mathbf n$, the difference $\mathbf S - \varepsilon _0 c E^2\mathbf n$ is $O(\delta \mathbf n).$

To sum up, what is the meaning of the relation $I \propto E^2$? In particular is it

1. An approximation of the exact law (see above). Or
2. Is it a definition? In this case, why is it a useful one?

Thank you in advance.

---

[1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486659577) Grant R. Fowles, “[Introduction to modern optics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486659577)”.

Comment: I am not sure that it is OK to equate intensity with flux. If you absorb all the energy of the EM wave at a given point the energy will be proportional to the time averaged amplitude of the E field. When you start to do vector addition of Poynting vectors you see the net _flow_ of energy but I don't think that is the same thing as intensity.

Comment: @Floris, the question asks about irradiance, which is defined in terms of Poynting flux. What do you mean by intensity?

Comment: @JánLalinský Intensity = energy per unit area. It does not have a direction unlike irradiance. I see that OP used the symbol $I$ (which I associate with intensity) for irradiance. As you said in your answer these become the same thing with simple wave fronts; the source of much confusion (including, it seems, mine).

Comment: How do you calculate energy per unit area? That should give zero for any EM field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The author confused things in section 3.1.

In macroscopic EM theory of radiation (radiometry), technically irradiance at a given point of a plane is defined as time average of the normal component of the Poynting vector (normal to the plane):

$$
I = \overline{\mathbf S \cdot \mathbf n}
$$

As you have shown, this is function of $|\mathbf E|^2$ only in some cases, like single plane wave; it also seems reasonable for isotropic thermal radiation. For general EM field, however, irradiance cannot be expressed as function of $|\mathbf E|^2$ only.

Comment: So I'm assuming that the proportionality refers to special cases where the wave directions are nearly the same - indeed this is the case with several interferometric devices.